# Windows上のrubyで中国語のファイルをrenameしたい。

Tags: ruby, windows

[環境]
Ruby 2.3.0
Windows 7 32bit 日本語環境

上記の環境において、中国語が含まれるファイルをリネームしようとするとエラーが発生します。
正常に処理するためには、どうすればよいのかアドバイスお願いします。
下記がサンプルプログラムです。

```
directory = '/hoge/'
count = 1
Dir::entries(directory).each{|d|
    File::rename( directory + d , count )
    count = count + 1
}
```

Comment: どのようなエラーがはっせいしていますか？

Comment: rename行で、no such file or directoryが発生します。

Comment: `directory`（`'/hoge'`）の末尾に`/`が無いですが、実際のコードでも無いのでしょうか。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。実際のファイルでは存在しています。ディレクトリ内に中国語のファイルが入っていない場合、リネームは成功します。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ファイル名のエンコーディング](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Dir.html#entries-method)を指定する必要があるのでは？

> entries( dirname ) → array
>   entries( dirname, encoding: enc ) → array

Comment: [日本語マニュアルに記述がない](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.3.0/class/Dir.html#S_ENTRIES)というのが、なんとも残念な状況ですね。かなり古い記述しか見つけられませんでした→[ファイル名のエンコーディング](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.3.0/class/IO.html#m17n)

Comment: ありがとうございます。エンコード指定で処理出来ました。

Comment: 今度からは、英語マニュアルも参照するようにします。ありがとうございました。